# Edit rejection of minor error in code

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits, editing-help

I don't want to call names here so I will not give a link (but may do so if required).

In an answer I suggested to replace

```
float** x = malloc(sizeof(float)*2);
```

with

```
float** x = malloc(sizeof(*x)*2);
```

because it is easier to maintain and the original was wrong the way it was. This was fixed by the author, but he added another mistake

```
float** x = malloc(sizeof(sizeof(*x)*2);
```

I didn't want to point that out again and instead just fixed it, because this was quite likely a copy/paste error than an intended piece of code. (while the first one was wrong,  there was more than one possible solutions, so I suggested a solution via comment)

The edit was ultimately approved but the one reviewer rejected with the reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's own

I don't understand how this is applicable here as I fixed a minor error which would break the code as presented, I would think this is in the intent of the post (author approved the edit).  This is the second time I saw this vote (can't remember which edit was the first time).

What am I doin wrong that might lead to the rejection?

Comment: Sadly reviewers are in general don't have enough skills in the [tag] subject to know that your edit was correct.  A major problem with the review system.  Your rep is motoring well, soon you'll no longer be subjected to such reviews.  Hang in there.  For now, use a comment to point out the mistake.

Comment: @HansPassant I will need 1 or 2 years till I have 2k rep if I stay in [c]. rep is hard earned there^^.

Comment: @KamiKaze I would say don't be too concerned about rep, but be concerned about learning and contributing, I focused on learning from SO and then contributing and rep is coming too

Comment: @AbdulKawee I am not. I just wanted to point out to Hans that "soon" is not that "soon"

Comment: @KamiKaze yeah I totally agree with you on that :) its definitely not "soon"

Comment: Could you link to the review? I can't find any indication of that edit either in the answers history nor in your suggest edits list. Did the owner of the answer reject your edit or someone in review?

Comment: @BDL https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19460003 as stated it was not ultimately rejected just by 1 reviewer.

Comment: Now I got it. I was confused because I thought you were also suggesting the first change. But apparently your meant "In an answer I left a comment to explain that X should be replaced by Y" instead of "I suggested to replace X with Y".

Answer (score 33):

I think Maroun has missed something important: SO actively discourages approving edits like this. That edit looks like an outside poster trying to fix the code. In most cases this is either a review audit, or someone who wants to reply to the answerer by adding or removing code. I probably would have rejected this edit myself.

What can you do about this? Leave a better comment. You wrote

> removed double sizeof

That simply describes *what* you did. Your comment should explain *why* you did it. So something like this would help reviewers understand the edit a little bit better

> Looks like a copy/paste error added two sizeof(). Removed one and it works.

That makes your review stand out a bit more. Most of the bad edits have poor comments. A well written comment solves a lot of problems.

Comment: "In most cases this is either a review audit" I really need to see such audit. Have any example?

Comment: @Braiam For suggested edits, the MO of the "random bad edit generator" is to edit code and/or text. I don't have a specific example off the top of my head

Comment: Good point. Although I still think that if someone not familiar with C, he should skip edits he's not sure about.

Comment: @Maroun With a good enough comment, reviewers are a lot more likely to skip something that requires specific knowledge (at least I know I would)

Comment: `SO actively discourages approving edits like this.`  this is misleading because it sounds like this is what the company wants, which isn't necessarily true.  The SO Community itself has established that edits to code should be avoided as moderation policy over the years.  And even then fixing mistakes in code is supposed to be a good edit.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Its important to note this is the tradeoff for audits that make you suspect edits like these. And even without the audits, I still run across the random edit where someone thinks the code would be better with this one tweak. Again, if you make a solid comment, your edit will stand out better

Comment: I understood the description differently. Because the examples are just 2 word statements. But I will remember this.

Comment: *he should skip edits he's not sure about* @Maroun True, but that still requires the reviewer to feel unsure.

Comment: @psubsee2003 "*And even then fixing mistakes in code is supposed to be a good edit*" In answers potentially, but in questions very rarely as it may fix the bug and thus people scratch their heads for ever.

Comment: It has never been so simple, it's "replace many random string of text anywhere". A single string edit would never been an audit.

Answer (score 12):

You're not doing anything wrong.

It happens (unfortunately) that users (sometimes badges seekers) reject edits without paying full attention to the content. The rule is very simple: If you know what you're doing, approve or reject, otherwise, just skip.

You can mention the user and let him know that he did a mistake, maybe he'll pay more attention next time.

But most importantly, keep up the good work and don't let things like that prevent you from contributing more and more.